# Files corrupted after space transfer between partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, data-corruption

So I was trying to move space from my windows partition to Ubuntu partition using Gparted using a live Ubuntu USB disk. Everything was going fine until out of nowhere the screen went black and then 'squashfs' errors started coming up. I forced shut down the system and booted again. Now my files in the windows partition from which I was taking space are corrupted and cannot be opened. Any help on how the files can be repaired will be much appreciated

Comment: I made the same mistake a month ago using Linux to manage `NTFS`, my ubuntu froze and I had to do a hard reset. But in my case `Ext4` partition was not adjacent to Windows partition. It was an expansion drive, I plugged it in to a Windows OS and used its disk management tool, luckily it fixed the partition, All my files were there.

Comment: Do not create any file in it before saving your filesystem. I stupidly did it while desperately attempting to rescue files from Ubuntu, I created a text file in it to list files in it hopig to get to know which files I lost, I issued `ls . >myfiles.txt` in the `NTFS`, it created 250 bytes of text file.I am sill unsure if that harmed the files or directories, though files look fine.

Comment: There is no way to "move" or "transfer" space between partitions, so it is unclear what happened. There is also no way to reliably fix Windows file system from Ubuntu, as the Windows filesystems are proprietary. I hope there is a backup, and if not, that now you know why it is needed.

Comment: What I did was create an unallocated partition from my C drive in Windows. Now I wanted to merge this with the Ubuntu partition which is placed after the Windows D drive. So I tried to merge this unallocated partition into the D drive and then from the D drive make another unallocated partition and give it to the Ubuntu partition. My windows is working fine, its only my files like documents, photos, etc (which are in the D drive) which wouldn't open although there is no change in their size. Hence, the question about how to repair those files.

Comment: If NTFS have you run chkdsk from Windows? If not in middle of resize it should be repairable, but abnormal shutdown can totally corrupt file system and chkdsk then may create more issues.

Comment: Most probably your files are not damaged. Your best bet will be to use Windows disk management and check that partition https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-open-disk-management-in-windows-10.html. Or ask for professional help.